# Change the scrollbar track color dynamically using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to change the scrollbar color based on user picked color. I was trying achieve the task with jquery. I was not able to change the track color.

https://jsfiddle.net/hoxtzL6o/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".container").css("color","blue");
    //$(".container::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb").css("background-color","blue !important")
  $(".container::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb").attr('style','background-color:blue')
})
```

I tried css and style attribute too.

Comment: Javascript cannot access pseudo selectors.

Comment: You'd have better to toggle a class because anyway you cannot target from js/jq the pseudo element scrollbar which isn't part of DOM. Other way would be to add your specific rule to stylesheet if for some reason you don't want to manage it in any hardcoded CSS rule. e.g: https://jsfiddle.net/hoxtzL6o/1/

Comment: I am not supposed to use stylesheet. Thats my hurdle. If the user pick x color, the scrollbar color should also change.

Comment: @AlaksandarJesusGene But then why not `document.styleSheets[0].addRule('.container::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb',"background-color:" + x + " !important");`

Answer (score 3):

Pseudo elements are not in the DOM flow. You can use jQuery or JS to append the stylesheet to document head. here is the jQuery

```
var styles = "<style type='text/css'>.container::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{background-color: blue}</style>";  

$(styles).appendTo('head');
```

**Edit:** Just saw the comments. You could do something like this. [Codepen Example](http://codepen.io/thelessergeek/pen/VKwLyz?editors=0010)

Also attached code snippet below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var color;
    var picker;
    var new_stylesheet;
    
    $('button').click(function getcolor(color, picker, new_stylesheet) {
      color = $(this).val();
      picker = ".outer::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {background:" + color + ";}";
      new_stylesheet = "<style type='text/css' id='currentCSS'>" + picker + "</style>";

      //check if stylsheet exists          
      existingStylesheet = $("#currentCSS");
      if (existingStylesheet.length) {$(existingStylesheet).replaceWith(new_stylesheet);}
      else {$(new_stylesheet).appendTo('head');}
    });
});
```

```css
.outer {height: 100px;width: 80%;overflow-y: scroll;border: 1px solid #ccc;}
.inner {height: 150px}
.outer::-webkit-scrollbar {width: 13px}
.outer::-webkit-scrollbar-track {background: #ccc;}
.outer::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {background: red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer"><div class="inner">scrollable area</div></div>
<button value="red">red by default</button>
<button value="blue">pick blue</button>
<button value="green">pick green</button>
```